# Open a local file from local html+js page

Tags: javascript, html, file, image-processing

Is it possible to show a dialog box to let the user select a file on the local drive and then read its content from a local html page using js?

Is it possible to save a file to a user chosen path?

I'm planning to write a simple script to open file and encode its content inside images (not steganography, just the file's raw bytes).

Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770107/read-csv-file-client-side/3770130#3770130

Comment: I've also asked if it can be saved. Anyway, thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with [newer HTML5 APIs supported by some browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications), but it's not universally supported (older IE versions, for example).